# Make delay of answer shorter

Tags: python, voice-recognition, voice, assistant, gtts

I am making voice assistant on python.
Here is the code:

```
import os
import time
import playsound
import speech_recognition as sr
from gtts import gTTS


def speak(text):
    tts = gTTS(text=text, lang="en")
    filename = "voice.mp3"
    tts.save(filename)
    playsound.playsound(filename)


def get_audio():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio = r.listen(source)
        said = ""

        try:
            said = r.recognize_google(audio)
            print(said)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception: " + str(e))

    return said

text = get_audio()

if "hello" in text:
    speak("Hi, how are you?")
```

And when I say "hello" it's thinking for 2 seconds, and then says "Hi, how are you?"
Maybe it's because I'm saving mp3 file? How to make program answer without delay?

Comment: Did you try recognising a previously-recorded file to see how long that takes? Did you try timing how long the capture takes and comparing to the overall time to recognise? Use time.perf_counter https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html

Comment: Just ' time.perf_counter() ' ?   Without ' time.perf_counter(2) ' ?

Comment: Not sure what the 2 is for. Use it as in first `starttime = time.perf_counter()` then your code you want to time then `elapsed=starttime-time.perf_counter()` and use elapsed...

Comment: Oops I meant `elapsed=time.perf_counter()-starttime`

Comment: Wow! It works! A little bit faster) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
import time
import playsound
import speech_recognition as sr
from gtts import gTTS

starttime = time.perf_counter()

def speak(text):
    tts = gTTS(text=text, lang="en")
    filename = "voice.mp3"
    tts.save(filename)
    playsound.playsound(filename)

elapsed=time.perf_counter()-starttime    

def get_audio():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio = r.listen(source)
        said = ""

        try:
            said = r.recognize_google(audio)
            print(said)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception: " + str(e))

    return said

text = get_audio()

if "hello" in text:
    speak("Hi, how are you?")
```